# Why does ReactJS.net not have an import statement for React?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, reactjs.net

I am playing around with https://reactjs.net/ , and want to setup an application inside my existing ASP.NET MVC application.

I have made a couple of simple React applications using the "default installation template" inside Visual Studio, but not based on ReactJS.net and where the content is only a subpage.

However, if I take the tutorial template used as examples:

```
var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox">
                Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
      </div>
        );
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

There are no importing React like: `import * as React from 'react';` , which I am used to.

So my question is: why not? And when are you supposed to import React?

Comment: It's probably abstracted out in the website. You absolutely have to import `React` in any file you want to use it in your web app

Answer (score 0):

Because `import React from 'react';` is required when you are trying to import npm packages. Reactjs.Net doesn't use npm dependency and you're required to put the CDNs in your view using `<script src="">`. Basically, you're importing React automatically when you use the CDNs